# What exactly is preferSlave in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, cloud-foundry, master-slave

What does the setting `targetServerType` with value `preferSlave` in the PostgreSQL JDBC driver really mean?

The reason why I am asking this question is according to the documentation:

> > targetServerType = String
>
> Allows opening connections to only servers with the required state, the
>   allowed values are any, master, slave, secondary, preferSlave and
>   preferSecondary. The master/slave distinction is currently done by
>   observing if the server allows writes. The value preferSecondary tries
>   to connect to secondary if any are available, otherwise allows falls
>   back to connecting also to master.

Now I was trying this setup in Cloudfoundry and if I was to look at the metrics of PostgreSQL on the dashboard, I still see reads being done on the master. Hence my question. Isn't master nodes supposed to be used for reads in this case?

And how does it affect performance in terms of read/write. Especially in an application where the writes are done with the target as master and reads are done with the target `preferslave`?

Comment: Where did you find those parameters?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I assume https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html section "Connection Fail-over" (although the value is `preferSlave`, not `preferredSlave`).

Comment: I assume you mean `preferSlave`. If so, did you read the documentation, what is unclear?

Comment: Do you actually have multiple nodes, and did you specify those nodes individually in your connection string as specified in the documentation of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver?

Comment: As far as CF is concerned 2 separate URL's are provided for reads(target=preferreSlave) and writes(target master) connections. So yes I believe, the nodes are used separately.

Comment: Please be precise (and that includes don't typos in important things like settings), and provide all relevant information in your question. In any, case have you looked at https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html (at the end), and what part of that is unclear?